# How to inject a SpanContext into a TextMapCarrier type

Tags: c++, open-telemetry

I'm trying to inject a SpanContext object into a TextMapCarrier.

```cpp
MyTextMapCarrier<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>> carrier;
auto prop = opentelemetry::context::propagation::GlobalTextMapPropagator::GetGlobalPropagator();
prop->Inject(carrier, span->GetContext());
```

With the above code I get this error:

```cpp
[1/2] Building CXX object myapp.cpp.o
In file included .....
/usr/include/opentelemetry/context/context.h: In instantiation of 'opentelemetry::v1::context::Context::DataList::DataList(const T&) [with T = opentelemetry::v1::trace::SpanContext]':
/usr/include/opentelemetry/context/context.h:30:41:   required from 'opentelemetry::v1::context::Context::Context(const T&) [with T = opentelemetry::v1::trace::SpanContext]' myapp.cpp:63:14:   required from here
/usr/include/opentelemetry/context/context.h:111:7: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
  111 |       for (auto &iter : keys_and_vals)
```

This error message suggests that SpanContext, unlike Context, does not implement `begin()` and `end()`.

But according to [OpenTelemetry Docs: Propagators API: Inject](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/context/api-propagators/#inject), it should be the case?

Build for Alpine Linux Alpine:20230901 and OpenTelemetry 1.11.